# adding quantity to related products in magento backend

Tags: php, xml, magento

I'm new to magento and trying to add quantity column to the grid in related products tab (edit product -> related products).
this is what I did:

- overwrite related.php file:

```
Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Related.php
```

- added to `_prepareCollection()` method this code:

```
$collection->joinField(
    'qty',
    'cataloginventory_stock_item',
    'qty',
    'product_id = entity_id',
    '{{table}}.stock_id = 1',
    'left'
);
```

- and added `to _prepareColumns()` methods this code:

```
$this->addColumn('qty', 
    array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('QTY'),
        'width'     => 80,
        'index'     => 'qty'
```

Now I can see the new column but the quantity is float number (for example 100.00) and I can't filter results based on my new `QTY` column.

My questions:

1. is that all I need to add column or I have to do some thing else??
2. how to display QTY in integer format (for example 100 not 100.00)??
3. why I can't filter results based on the QTY??

any idea will be appreciated, Thanks in advance..

Comment: No ideas? .. I can't go to page 2 after adding new column

Answer (score 1):

Quantity as integer format

```
'getter'    => array($this, 'getFormattedQty')

public function getFormattedQty($row)
{
   return intVal($row->getQtyOrdered());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To cover the three questions simply add the `'type'` option with the value set to `'number'` in the to `_prepareColumns()` method. Example Below:

```
    $this->addColumn('qty', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('QTY'),
        'type'      => 'number',
        'width'     => 80,
        'index'     => 'qty'
    ));
```

This will set the value as a whole number or integer rather than a float and will let you filter for a particular range.

I have used this myself to add the QTY to the Associated Products grid.